# Does OpenXML support events?

Tags: c#, openxml

My web application (c#) is using OpenXML to export data into Excel files. I am looking to implement Worksheet.Change event. I looked around and I don't see any mentions of event handling with OpenXML. Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenXML is just a file format.  There's no Excel running when you use it.